# Testing for differential median

Tags: biostatistics, median, epidemiology

In my study, I have two groups, one exposure group (e.g. population A with disease) and a non-exporure group (population B without the disease) and I am interested in the outcome "Death". Data are matched, therefore, for each patient with the disease there are up to 10 patients without the disease. I have calculated the "Median age at death" for each group and by gender. The results show that median age (IQR) at death for female in the exposure group is 55 (18) while in the female of the non-exposure group is 60 (18). The median age (IQR) at death for male in the exposure group is 56 (14) while median age at death for make in the unexposed group is 57 (16). 
I would like to test the differential in the medians (e.g. is the differential in median age at death between exposed vs unexposed within female significantly different between the differential in median age at death between exposed and unexposed within the male group?), however I am not sure how to do that since not everybody in my exposure or unexposure group die.